# How to convert db2 date format to H2 date format for in memory testing in java

Tags: java, junit, db2, h2, in-memory-database

I am trying to convert the DB2 data base Date field format into H2 in memory database date format as shown below. It did not work for me. 
Please help.

```
select CREATE_DATE from PX.MY_DB2TABLE ;
```

Here DB2 DATE format in database table is 'MM/DD/YYYY'.  CREATE_DATE is DATE data type in db2.

H2 database is accepting only 'yyyy-MM-dd' format.

Tried the following way in H2:

```
  select PARSEDATETIME(CREATE_DATE,'MM/dd/yyyy') FROM PX.MY_DB2TABLE;
    select PARSEDATETIME(CREATE_DATE,'yyyy-MM-dd') FROM PX.MY_DB2TABLE;
```

Error:
Cannot parse DATE constant

Comment: An actual `DATE` type doesn't have a format.  Dates are only formatted when output as something else.  How are you accessing both databases?  If you're using one of the java ORM layer managers (ie, JPA), or most of the available drivers, the type transitions would be managed for you; when the query came back from the DB, you should be getting `java.time.LocalDate` (older drivers might be limited to the old javal.sql.X types, though).

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a character-string representation from a DATE data-type value with the format 'YYYY-MM-DD', the DATE field selected in the original query [from the OP] can be wrapped in a CHAR casting scalar with an additional argument requesting that particular date-formatting for the **Datetime to character** casting; no mention of which variant of DB2, but here is some doc: [DB2 for Linux UNIX and Windows 9.7.0->Database fundamentals->SQL->Functions->Scalar functions->CHAR](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000777.html):

```
select CHAR(CREATE_DATE, ISO) from PX.MY_DB2TABLE ;
```

For the second argument, see **Date Strings** *Table 1. Formats for String Representations of Dates* in [imagining LOCAL as the valid argument, in place of the LOC as seen in the *table*]:
[DB2 for Linux UNIX and Windows 9.7.0->Database fundamentals->SQL->Language elements->Data types->Data type list->Datetime values](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008474.html)